# Write data to excel using Apache POI with TestNG framework

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, testng, hssf

I am trying to write data to excel sheet using Apache POI.I am using TestNG framerwork and eclipse IDE. Program is executing successfully without any error.But when I click refresh on my project source, excel sheet is not coming. Please tell me how will I see my generated excel sheet.
My code is as below:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("User.xls");
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("worksheet");
            HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.createRow((short) 0);
            HSSFCell cell1 = row1.createCell((short) 0);
            cell1.setCellValue("abc");
            HSSFCell cell2 = row1.createCell((short) 1);
            cell2.setCellValue("123");
            workbook.write(fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What path you have given to generate excel sheet? Post some of your code for better understanding.

Comment: public class Test{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  try{FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("User.xls");
   HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();
   HSSFSheet worksheet=workbook.createSheet("worksheet");
   HSSFRow row1=worksheet.createRow((short)0);
   HSSFCell cell1=row1.createCell((short)0);
   cell1.setCellValue("abc");
   
   HSSFCell cell2=row1.createCell((short)1);
   cell2.setCellValue("123");
   workbook.write(fos);
   fos.close();
   
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();}}}

Comment: Please help where i did wrong???

Comment: Can you find it in project's root directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your project's root directory. It should be there by default. If you have specified the working directory in your run configuration -> arguments, you should check that folder. Besides, you can always get the complete file path in Java.

```
System.out.println(new File("User.xls").getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way to create file

```
FileOutputStream out =
            new FileOutputStream(new File("User.xls"));
```

This file  will be stored in your class directory folder.

Ex: (`Test.java` is stored in (`c://Workspace//src//Test.java)` , the file also will store in same path `c://Workspace//src//User.xls"`)